# Let $P_0 \subsetneq P_{1} \subsetneq \dotsb \subsetneq P_n$ be a chain of prime ideals in a Noetherian ring.

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $P_0 \subset P_{1} \subset \dotsb \subset P_n$ be a chain of prime ideals in a Noetherian ring.
>
> Show that if $x \in P_n$ then there exists a chain of prime ideals $Q_{1} \subsetneq \dotsb \subsetneq Q_n = P_n$ such that $x \in Q_1$.

I'm lost on how to tackle this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If $x \in P_n$ and $P_n \subset P_{n-1} \subset \ldots \subset P_0$ then can't you trivially let $Q_i = P_i$ and then $x\in Q_i$ for all $0 \le i \le n$ because if $x \in P_n$ then $x \in P_i$ for all such $i$? I think we are missing some important condition or information.

Comment: Sorry. Reverse all the inclusions!

Comment: Is $x\in Q_1$ or $x\in Q_0$? and is there a relationship between $P_k$ and $Q_k$ for $k<n$ ?

Comment: There need not be any relationship between the $P_i$ and $Q_i$'s. (Apart from $P_n = Q_n$ of course!). And yes, we need $x \in Q_1$. Not necessarily in $Q_0$.

Comment: The title does not match the question. Which is right?

Comment: Sorry. Okay, everything in the question is now correctly stated. (I hope.)

Answer (score -1):

This is Lemma 2.5.13 in Qing Liu's book *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*. The proof here uses [Krull's principal ideal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem) to employ induction on $n$.

I find the proof quite non-trivial, definitely not something I would come up with. I don't know if there is an elementary way to prove it. As an aside, Liu then uses this lemma to deduce that Noetherian local rings have finite dimension (in fact the dimension is bounded by the number of generators needed for the unique maximal ideal) in Corollary 5.14.